# Calculating theoretical speedup using Amdahl's Law

Tags: performance, parallelism-amdahl

Hi I just wanted to get some thoughts on my working out on this question.

> Using Amdahl's law calculate the maximum theoretical speedup for a program comprised of 82% parallel code and 18% serial code running on 8 processing cores

My thoughts is that - only the parallel code gets sped up therefore the calculation would be:

1/(0.82/8)+(0.18/1)

Is this correct? If not - could someone explain where I went wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating the maximum speedup with parallelization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59918307/calculating-the-maximum-speedup-with-parallelization)